# How to make “algorithm” environment split in pages and change the environment name from “Algorithm 1” to “Method 1” at same time？

Tags: algorithms

the first part of my question is solved by put this code

```
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
  {% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
   \begin{center}
     \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
     \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
     \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
       {\raggedright\textbf{\ALG@name~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
       \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
       \else % #1 is not \relax
         \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
       \fi
       \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
     }
  }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
     \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
   \end{center}
  }
\makeatother
```

before  `\begin{document}` , however that makes me unable to change the algorithm environment name by `\floatname{algorithm}{\textbf{method}}`. How could i solve the two problem at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ and which algorithm-related packages are loaded in the preamble of your document.

Comment: The document class is book. I use package "algorithm" and "algorithmc"